# Firebird database with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, firebird

When i execute `rake db:schema:dump` i get in schema.rb:
*Could not dump table "xxx" because of following NoMethodError

undefined method `limit' for "INTEGER":String*

This is problem with app because on new database i got this same error.
Im using flamerobin and i need to use it for creating db.

Im using https://github.com/rowland/activerecord-fb-adapter to connect to my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i just reinstall my ruby do everything from the begining (i need to move fbclient.dll from firebird install folder to Disk:ruby/bin) and now everything works great :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not the only one having this issue apparently: https://github.com/rowland/activerecord-fb-adapter/issues/67. Seems to be a gem issue.

Comment: This is also my question :)